# UDP broadcast being sent, but not received (yes, again)

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, broadcast

I have a question seemingly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496761/udp-broadcast-being-sent-but-not-received), yet having checked that and others I can't see the difference.

I have an app that receives UDP broadcasts. It loops back on itself properly, and can on the same machine receive from another app. However, when I try to receive from an external GoPro Hero4 Black,

- I can send and receive TCP with the camera within the same app
- Another app on the same machine can receive the UDP broadcasts from the camera
- This app sees nothing

I checked for properly using INADDR_ANY, and it's being done in the code. Given the machine does receive the packets, and the app itself can do TCP with the camera, the error has to be in the UDP receive code, yet that works between apps on the same machine.

Question: What could cause this behavior?

My belief is the problem is in my understanding of UDP broadcast receive, but nevertheless, in response to a comment, here's code. This initializes the receiver:

```
int yudpsocket_server(const char *addr,int port) {
    //create socket
    int socketfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    int reuseon   = 1;
    int r = -1;
    //bind
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_len    = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if (addr == NULL || strlen(addr) == 0 || strcmp(addr, BROADCAST_IP) == 0) {
        r = setsockopt( socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &reuseon, sizeof(reuseon) );
        serv_addr.sin_port        = htons(port);
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    } else {
        r = setsockopt( socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseon, sizeof(reuseon) );
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        memset( &serv_addr, '\0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    }
    if (r == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    r = bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (r==0) {
        return socketfd;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And this does the receive:

```
int yudpsocket_receive(int socket_fd, char *outdata, int expted_len, char *remoteip, int* remoteport) {
    struct sockaddr_in  cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    memset(&cli_addr, 0x0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    int len = (int)recvfrom(socket_fd, outdata, expted_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
    char *clientip = inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr);
    memcpy(remoteip, clientip, strlen(clientip));
    *remoteport = cli_addr.sin_port; // Maybe not right - s.b. ntohs()?
    return len;
}
```

Comment: A bug in your code, of course. Yet not seeing code I can't tell you where the bug is.

Comment: What is `BROADCAST_IP` in your code?

Comment: I also do not see any check for result of setsockopt.

Comment: There is `static char* BROADCAST_IP = "255.255.255.255";` earlier in the file.

Comment: Can't argue about checking the result; what might be different in the environment that would cause this to work locally but not from an external source?

Comment: It could be that your UDP broadcast packets are not coming through network router or anything. But you are saying that another application on the same machine sees them, which rules out this option. So it has to be your app. Create a very small example of the code (10 lines of main) and see if it sees packets. If it doesn't, post the code. If it does, start adding functionality.

Comment: Routers won't forward 255.255.255.255. Try a LAN-local broadcast address. NB you have a `memset()` in the wrong place., that clobbers what was done into previous two lines. I don't think it should be there at all.